# JTable -> TableModeListener

Tags: java, event-handling, jtable

I have this `JTable` having a `DefaultTableModel` as its model.
On the table I have several swing component, `JComboBox` and `JCheckBox`, set on a particular column via `DefaultCellEditor` and `DefaultCellRenderer`.
The `TableModelListener` was added to the table to capture changes on editable columns.
The rest of the columns will display details of the selected component, i.e. item code -> item price, item count, item classification,etc.

I have this problem wherein if the selectedItem of the `JComboBox(itemCode)` changes, the items of the other `JComboBox(itemClassification)` changes. But together with the change of the other JComboBox I need to display the item price on the same table. This change refires the `valueChanged` method which makes an infinite loop of `valueChanged`.

How can I get rid of the infinite loop thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to check the update event to see what column the event is for and ignore columns that are automatically updated:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableProcessing extends JPanel implements TableModelListener
{
    public TableProcessing()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Quantity", "Price", "Cost"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Bread", new Integer(1), new Double(1.11), new Double(1.11)},
            {"Milk", new Integer(1), new Double(2.22), new Double(2.22)},
            {"Tea", new Integer(1), new Double(3.33), new Double(3.33)},
            {"Cofee", new Integer(1), new Double(4.44), new Double(4.44)}
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }

            //  The Cost is not editable
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
            {
                return (column == 3) ? false : true;
            }
        };
        model.addTableModelListener( this );

        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );

        String[] items = { "Bread", "Milk", "Tea", "Coffee" };
        JComboBox<String> editor = new JComboBox<String>( items );

        DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( editor );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(dce);
    }

    /*
     *  The cost is recalculated whenever the quantity or price is changed
     */
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
        {
            int row = e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();

            if (column == 1 || column == 2)
            {
                TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                int quantity = ((Integer)model.getValueAt(row, 1)).intValue();
                double price = ((Double)model.getValueAt(row, 2)).doubleValue();
                Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
                model.setValueAt(value, row, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Model Listener");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableProcessing());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft, I never know which is the better approach. Removing/adding a listener has the benefit of not firing an event. Its good to have a couple of options.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the listener when making changes from within the listener itself, and then re-add it when done with changes.  Or you could give the Listener a boolean property that activates and deactivates the listener code, and set it appropriately from within the listener.

Comment: +1, always a good trick to avoid infinite loops within listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Actually...
I have also my answer.
I just get into the API of TableModelListener and I found the TableModelEvent.getColumn()

Thanks guys...

Comment: I gave you that answer earlier. I guess you won't need my help the next time so I won't bother answering again.

Comment: @camickr: I apologize for it... I would need your help, anybodies help for any problem I'm on.