# TableModelListener to change the model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablemodel

I have implemented a TableModelListener that properly behaves with executing callback to tableChanged() upon a model change by the user. Now, I need to implement a logic where user will update one cell, I will catch this event, and then update another cell based on that. However, once I change the model inside tableChanged(), it causes another listener invocation, again that calls the tableChanged() in an infinite loop. So, is there a proper way to handle such logic?

Comment: Are you only listening to one column and making changes to another?

Comment: Well, fix the listener so that it ends up not changing the model anymore at some point. If you posted your code and explained what the listener is supposed to do, it would be easier to help. Note that a listener is not needed to to that. The setValueAt() method can simply modify the other related value, and fire the appropriate events.

Comment: Usually you listen for changes to a specific column only. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800

Comment: Thank you camickr, That is a better practice for sure, and it answered my question.

Comment: In the future, please ask a more complete question.