# JTable edit on selection not working when pressing down key while editing a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The problem only happens when there are two `JTables`. `TableB` listens to `TableA` and changes it's contents based on the changes applied to `TableA`.

Without `TableB`, `TableA` behaves fine. When pressing the down arrow while editing a cell, the focus goes to the cell below and the cell contents become highlighted and user can change the entire contents of the cell.

With `TableB` in the picture, when pressing the down arrow while editing a cell `stopEditing()` is triggered in `TableA` (good), `TableB` is notified of a change in `TableA` and updates it's own data. At this point the focus is lost in `TableA` (bad). `TableA` should at this point have focus going to the cell below in the editing stage.

I have tried gaining focus back to `TableA` via:

```
TableA.requestFocusInWindow();
TableA.setSelectedCell(TableA.getSelectedRow(), getEditableColumn());
```

The problem is the cell is selected but it's supposed to be in the editing stage not just being selected.

I then tried:

```
TableA.editCellAt( TableA.getSelectedRow( ),  getEditableColumn() );
```

But the above line didn't seem to do anything.

What should I do to prevent the resizing/repainting of `TableB` from affecting the focus and behavior or `TableA`?

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, this will lead to less confusion and better answers.

Answer (score 0):

> when pressing the down arrow while editing a cell stopEditing() is triggered in TableA (good), TableB is notified of a change in TableA and updates it's own data.

Use a `TableModelListener` to listen for changes in the data in a table.

Check out: [JTable -> TableModeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800) for a simple example to get you started. The example updates data in the same table, so you would obviously need to change it to update the TableModel of the other table.

Comment: I'm currently using the TableModelListener to change the other table.

Comment: @user1144251, well you were asked hours ago to post your `MCVE` that demonstrates the problem. You haven't so we can't keep guessing what you may or may not be doing.