# How can I get the value of cell changed in JTable on pressing Enter?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, edit

How can I get the value of cell changed in `JTable` on pressing Enter? When I filter data I can't get value.

```
tableEmployeFiltrer.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) 
    {
        String numDossier= tableEmployeFiltrer.getValueAt(evt.getFirstRow(),0).toString();
         float delai=Float.valueOf(tableEmployeFiltrer.getValueAt(evt.getFirstRow(), evt.getColumn()).toString()); 
         mapRecuperer.put(numDossier, delai);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tableEmployeFiltrer.getValueAt(evt.getFirstRow(), evt.getColumn()));   
    }
});
```

Comment: Please find shorter and more informative question titles and keep the details to your question body. You should consider being little bit more understandable.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: A `TableModelListener` should work. You may want to check the event to make sure it is an update event. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800 for a working `MCVE/SSCCE`.