# Get selected row of JTable when itemStateChanged in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I am trying to fetch the current row data while clicking on the combox.
My problem is that if I try to fetch the details on clicking the combobox the data retrieved is wrong.

This is populating invalid data in the collection. Please follow exact steps mentioned below to replicate.

Please run the code to replicate the issue as it works only during initial selection but not after.

NOTE: Please CLICK DIRECLTY ONLY ON THE SECOND COLUMN

```
Step 1: Click on Second Column of Row 1
Step 2: Select- Item 1 
Step 3: Click on Second Column of Row 2
Step 4: Select- Item 2
Step 5: Click on Second Column of Row 3
Step 6: Select- Item 3
WORKS Fine till here :)
Step 7 : Click on Second column of Row 1 and do not change an selection leave it as it is (Just click on the combobox twice)
Step 8 : Click on Second column of Row 2, DO NO CHANGES
Step 9 : Click on Second column of Row 3, DO NO CHANGES
Step 10: NOW randomly click on any of the second columns of rows(1,2,3) and see the output datamap. It really wierd why the event is
```

Below is the sample code:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestJCombo extends JFrame {

    public TestJCombo() {
        initialize();
    }

    JTable jTable;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    Map<Integer, String> dataMap;

    private void initialize() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setSize(50000, 25);
        field.setText("                                                                                           ");

        jTable = new JTable();

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.addItem("item 1");
        comboBox.addItem("item 2");
        comboBox.addItem("item 3");
        comboBox.setEditable(false);

        dataMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

                    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();

                    int selectedRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
                    selectedRow = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                    if (selectedRow != -1) {
                        String user = (String) jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
                        String data = "Row: " + (selectedRow + 1) + " :::: " + user + " , "
                                + comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                        dataMap.put(selectedRow + 1, "[" + user + " - " + comboBox.getSelectedItem() + "]");
                        if (selected != null) {
                            field.setText(data);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Current data map:: " + dataMap);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        jTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jTable.setRowHeight(30);
        jTable.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        DefaultTableModel myTableMdl = new DefaultTableModel();
        myTableMdl.addColumn("User");
        myTableMdl.addColumn("Role");
        jTable.setModel(myTableMdl);

        jTable.getColumn("Role").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        Vector tableData;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            tableData = new Vector();
            tableData.add("User " + i);
            myTableMdl.addRow(tableData);
        }

        getContentPane().add(jTable);
        getContentPane().add(field);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestJCombo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The `JTable.getValueAt` method takes view indexes, not model indexes. Right before you use this method, you are converting the view index to a model index, and using a model index in that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong listener on the wrong component. You should not be adding a listener to the combo box. The point of using an editor is to edit the data and update the `TableModel`. You should not be referencing the combo box for further processing.

So instead you should be adding a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. Then a `TableModelEvent` will be generated whenever the value in column 2 is changed. The `TableModelEvent` will contain the row/column information of the cell that was changed.

You can check out: [JTable -> TableModeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800) for a basic example of using a TableModelListener. In your case you check if the second column changed and then you update your map.

Also note you are using the convertRowIndexToModel() method incorrectly:

```
selectedRow = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
...
    String user = (String) jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
```

First of all you only need to worry about coverting the row index if the table view is sorted or filtered. In the code provided you don't do either so there is no need to convert the index.

However, if you ever did sort of filter the view then you would need convert the view row to the model row and then you must access the data from the model, not the view. So the code would be:

```
String user = (String) jTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
```

Comment: As suggested I have removed the code "selectedRow = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);" Thank you .. However the solution given by @M. Al Jumaily works perfectly with the added double action check – –

Comment: @Anonymous, `the solution given by Jumaily works perfectly` - its not a matter of working, its a matter of using the proper class for the job. You in no way need to extend JTable to get the desired functionality you require. You don't use a "hammer" for every job around the house. You use the proper tool. The fact that someone writes the code for you doesn't mean you should use the code. Learn to use Java effectively by using classes the way they are designed to be used. In any case don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: TableModelListener is good approach and it is also working fine. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are creating one `JComboBox` and then putting it on all the cells in the column. You are referencing the `JComboBox`, not creating a new one for each cell. This is why when you follow the *10 steps* you mentioned, the result is obtained is wildly foolish and senseless.

Here is the fix, create a custom [`TableCellEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) for all the cells that are in column 1 (Role column). The goal is to create a brand new `JComboBox`for each cell. This is achieved by changing the declaration of the `JTable` to `jtable = new JTable(){...};` to override the `getCellEditor(...){...}` method. Also, the method `private JComboBox createComboBox() {...}` is what you need for brand new `JComboBox` creation.

Now, we will take out the `addItemListener` and replace it with `addActionListener`. This is needed because the `itemStateChanged` in `ItemListener` will be not invoked if the user selects the item that is already selected. We need to somewhat replicate a two-mouse-click, one for showing the dropdown list and the second for selecting the item (you can skip this step if not needed).

I have also edited your code to make it more readable and efficient .

Here is an MVCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestJCombo extends JFrame {

    JTable jTable;
    //JComboBox comboBox;//not needed, replaced by the createComboBox() method.
    Map<Integer, String> dataMap;
    final JTextField FIELD = new JTextField(25);//must put this globally.
    //Since it is final, it should be all in upper case

    //It is a good practice to put the global variables on top and constructor(s) below.
    public TestJCombo() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        //use pack(); instead setSize(...); I used it at the end of this method.
        //setSize(300, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //both lines not needed, it has been taken care of when FIELD was declared.
        //FIELD.setSize(50000, 25);
        //FIELD.setText("                                         "
        //  + "                                                  ");

        //Must create a seperate TableCellEditor for each cell in the table.
        jTable = new JTable() {
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
                //if the cell lies in the second column, create a custom cell editor.
                if (modelColumn == 1) {
                    return (TableCellEditor) new DefaultCellEditor(createComboBox());
                } else {
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
                }
            }
        };

        //comboBox = new JComboBox();
        //comboBox.setEditable(true);
        //comboBox.addItem("item 1");
        //comboBox.addItem("item 2");
        //comboBox.addItem("item 3");
        //comboBox.setEditable(false);
        dataMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        jTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jTable.setRowHeight(30);
        jTable.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        DefaultTableModel myTableMdl = new DefaultTableModel();
        myTableMdl.addColumn("User");
        myTableMdl.addColumn("Role");
        jTable.setModel(myTableMdl);

        //we have our own custom CellEditor, this is not needed
        //jTable.getColumn("Role").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        Vector tableData;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            tableData = new Vector();
            tableData.add("User " + i);
            myTableMdl.addRow(tableData);
        }

        //It is better practice to add everything to a 
        //panel and then add that panel to the frame.
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(jTable);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));//add some space
        panel.add(FIELD);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();//should use this.
    }

    private JComboBox createComboBox() {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.addItem("item 1");
        comboBox.addItem("item 2");
        comboBox.addItem("item 3");
        comboBox.setEditable(false);

        //Add an ActionListener so that it would also detect if the user selects
        //the same item. The itemStateChanged in the ItemListener will not be
        //invoked if the user selects the item that is already selected.
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //To update the result everytime the user selects an item
            //(regardless if it was selected or not), we need to "mock"
            //a two-click operation. The first click will show the 
            //drop-down list to select from and the second will
            //allow the user to select the desired choice to be selected.
            boolean doubleClick = false;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (doubleClick) {
                    int selectedRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
                    selectedRow = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                    Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    if (selectedRow != -1 && selected != null) {
                        String user = (String) jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
                        String data = "Row: " + (selectedRow + 1) + " :::: " + user + " , "
                            + comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                        dataMap.put(selectedRow + 1, "[" + user + " - "
                            + comboBox.getSelectedItem() + "]");
                        FIELD.setText(data);
                        System.out.println("Current data map:: " + dataMap);
                    }
                    doubleClick = false;
                }
                doubleClick = true;
            }
        });

//      comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
//
//          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
//              if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
//
//                  Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
//
//                  int selectedRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
//                  selectedRow = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
//                  if (selectedRow != -1) {
//                      String user = (String) jTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
//                      String data = "Row: " + (selectedRow + 1) + " :::: " + user + " , "
//                          + comboBox.getSelectedItem();
//                      dataMap.put(selectedRow + 1, "[" + user + " - "
//                      + comboBox.getSelectedItem() + "]");
//                      if (selected != null) {
//                          FIELD.setText(data);
//                      }
//                      System.out.println("Current data map:: " + dataMap);
//                  }
//              }
//
//          }
//      });
        return comboBox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestJCombo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution finally WORKED I have implemented your suggestion and it worked perfectly. The added double action performed check also helped... Thank you

Comment: (1-) although this may work it is not the way to go about solving the problem. The `ActionListner` of the combo box is used by the `JTable` to update the `TableModel` when a value is selected. If you want to know when data is changed then use a `TableModelListener` to implement your custom logic.