# getting sum of jtable values continuously

Tags: java, swing

I want to get the sum of all the values from jtable continuously. Like I have made a jtable where the user will put data continuously and whenever a new row will insert in the jtable then some code should execute for taking all the sum of values of jtable and then set it on a text filed. I have written the code but I don't that in which event I should use the code so that when a new row is inserted in the table then the code runs and get the new sum of all values and store in a text field. So now in which method of jtable I should use this code so when a new row is inserted so that code executes.
The code is here...

```
    int rows=productionTable.getRowCount();
    int totalBundles=0;
    int totalBoxes=0;

    //totalBundles
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        totalBundles=totalBundles+Integer.parseInt(productionTable.getValueAt(i, 1)+"");

    }
    this.totalBundlesTextField.setText(totalBundles+"");
    //

    //totalBoxes
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        totalBoxes=totalBoxes+Integer.parseInt(productionTable.getValueAt(i, 2)+"");

    }
    this.totalBoxesTextField.setText(totalBoxes+"");
    //
```

Answer (score 1):

> So now in which method of jtable I should use this code so when a new row is inserted so that code execute

You do this when the data in the `TableModel` changes. So you can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel` of your table. Then a `TableModelEvent` will be generated when you:

1. add rows of data
2. remove rows of data
3. change the value of existing data

In each of the above cases you could then iterate through the `TableModel` to calculate the new value.

Check out [JTable -> TableModeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800) for a simple example of use a `TableModelListener`.

The above approach assumes that you don't have a lot a data in your model, since it recalculates the value each time a change is made.

If you have a lot of data this is not very efficient so you may want to keep a running total of the value in your TableModel. So you would need to customize the TableModel to keep a total. And then in methods like setValueAt(...), insertRow(...), removeRow(...) you would need to add logic to update the total as the model is updated.