# How do I uncheck a JCheckBox that I am using as one of my header columns?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, jtableheader

My JCheckBox "check all" header column works in that if I check the box, all checkboxes in this column become checked. I want to make it so that if you check the checkbox header so that all the boxes in the column become checked, uncheck one of the checkboxes in the column after will uncheck the checkbox header.

```
public class TablePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public TablePanel() {
        initComponents();
        populateStringArrays(); //populate string arrays that will populate my table
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        setWidthOfTable();
        loadTable(); //loads table with my array
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setHeaderRenderer(new BoxRenderer(new MyItemListener()));    
}


public class BoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer, MouseListener{

        String columnTitle = "Rings";
        protected BoxRenderer rendererComponent;
        int column;
        boolean mousePressed = false;

        public BoxRenderer(ItemListener listener){
            rendererComponent = this;
            rendererComponent.addItemListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
           if(table != null){
                JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
                if(header != null){       
                        rendererComponent.setForeground(header.getForeground());
        rendererComponent.setBackground(header.getBackground());
                            rendererComponent.setFont(header.getFont());
                            Border border = header.getBorder();

        header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
                       rendererComponent.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEADING); 
                            rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);  
                            header.addMouseListener(rendererComponent);
                    }
               }
               setColumn(column);
               rendererComponent.setText(columnTitle);
           return rendererComponent;
        }

        protected void setColumn(int column) {
            this.column = column;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        protected void handleClickEvent(MouseEvent e) {
            if (mousePressed) {
                mousePressed=false;
                JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader)(e.getSource());
                JTable tableView = header.getTable();
                TableColumnModel columnModel = tableView.getColumnModel();
                int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
                int column = tableView.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);

                if (viewColumn == this.column && e.getClickCount() == 1 && column != -1) {

                    doClick();
                }
            }
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JTableHeader)e.getSource()).repaint();
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePressed = true;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }



}

class MyItemListener implements ItemListener{

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                Object source = e.getSource();

                if (source instanceof AbstractButton == false){
                    return;}

                boolean checked = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
                System.out.println("Boolean checked = " + checked);

                if(checked == true){
                    checkAll();
                }else{
                    uncheckAll();
                }


        }

 }

private void checkAll(){

        for(int i=0; i<tableRecordArrayList.size(); i++){    

            table.getModel().setValueAt(true, i, 5);


        }

}

private void uncheckAll(){

        for(int i=0; i<tableRecordArrayList.size(); i++){ 
            table.getModel().setValueAt(false, i, 5);
        }

}

class TableModel extends javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel{


        /**Constructor**/

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return tableRecordArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        /**refresh for changes**/
        public void refreshTable(){
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            TableRecord record = tableRecordArrayList.get(row);
            switch(column){

                case 0:
                    return record.firstName;
                case 1:
                    return record.middleName;
                case 2:
                    return record.lastName;
                case 3:
                    return record.age;
                case 4:
                    return record.height;
                case 5:
                    return record.ring;

            }

            return "N/A";
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column){

            /**set the title of the columns of the table**/
            switch(column){

                case 0:
                    return "First Name";
                case 1:
                    return "Middle Name";
                case 2:
                    return "Last Name";
                case 3:
                    return "Age";
                case 4:
                    return "Height(cm)";
                case 5:
                    return "Has Championship Ring";

            }

            return "N/A";

        }

        /**turn column into checkboxes**/
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
            if(column == 5){
                return Boolean.class;
            }
            return String.class;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
            return column == 5;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object avalue, int row, int column){
            TableRecord record;
            Boolean v;
            switch(column){
                case 5:
                record = tableRecordArrayList.get(row);
                v = (Boolean) avalue;
                record.ring = v;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row,1);
                printArrayList();
                fireTableDataChanged();
                break;
            }
        }




}

}
```

this question has been solved. Please visit this link to find the solution.

https://coderanch.com/t/700630/java/uncheck-JCheckBox-header-columns#3288215

Comment: I have tried attaching a whole new header renderer to the table hoping it would uncheck it again but it didn't when I would uncheck of the cells in the column

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to make it so that if you check the checkbox header so that all the boxes in the column become checked, uncheck one of the checkboxes in the column after will uncheck the checkbox header.

Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`.

When the `TableModelEvent` is generated you can check if the data was changed in your column containing the checkbox and then reset the header checkbox when required.

Check out: [JTable -> TableModeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800) for a basic example of using a `TableModelListener`.

Comment: That's the thing, I dont know how to reset the header checkbox automatically. How can I turn the mouse clickevent that changes the state of my header checkbox into a function that does it without the mouse clicking part. I've tried many ways and found one close solution so far which is to set the header back to the default renderer then back to my checkbox renderer but the problem is it doesn't change right away and there is a delay.

Comment: @AMVPlusPlus, you invoke a doClick() method. I have no idea what that does but that would appear to me to be the place to start. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. That is create a table with hardcoded data using the DefaultTableModel. The only custom code should be your header renderer logic.

Comment: I was just looking at invoking a doClick() method but I just realized the painting part occurs here  ((JTableHeader)e.getSource()).repaint(); with this line so it means even if I invoke a doclick i need to target the header location. I created a global TableHeader variable and assigned it to  (JTableHeader)e.getSource()  to it thinking I can save the location but nothing so far. I can't believe there isn't something like this already been solved which seems like it would have so I guess it's good to have this here now.

Comment: @AMVPlusPlus, the above comment adds no useful information to the question. We are still waiting for [mcve].