# JComboBox in JTable does not update table instantly on item change

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JTable with JComboBoxes as the cell editor for one of the columns. When a user clicks one of the options in one of the comboboxes, the table cell should instantly be set to whatever option was chosen from the combobox. Sadly however, this does not happen until the user clicks elsewhere or presses Enter.

I understand that I could just take the value from the combobox but I would like to save the table to a file as soon as an option is chosen from any combobox in the table, and I haven't been able to find a way to dynamically identify which row a combobox belongs to so that the table could be updated on item change.

Is there a way to get the table to update with the chosen value as soon as the combobox item listener is fired?

Here is an example demonstrating this issue:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(450, 250);

    JTable table = new JTable(2, 1);

    TableColumn testColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);

    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.addItem("Item1");
    comboBox.addItem("Item2");
    comboBox.addItem("Item3");
    testColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0, 0));
            }
        }
    });

    frame.add(table);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. What do you mean you wish to save the table? So you wish for the comboBox within the cell to be replaced by the option itself?

Comment: The entire table will be saved as a tab delimited text file and wherever there is a combobox, the chosen option will be used for that cell. So yes, the combobox within the cell will be replaced by the chosen option when the table is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the table to update with the chosen value as soon as the combobox item listener is fired?

Don't depend on the ItemListener (or ActionListener). These events just indicate that the selected item of the combo box has changed.

Now the editor will take control and remove itself from the table and update the `TableModel` with the selected value.

If you want to know when data is changed in the `TableModel`, then add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`.

A `TableModelEvent` will be generated indicating the data has changed.

See: [JTable -> TableModeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800) for a simple example.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the ItemListener to a TableModelListener and it worked just fine.