# JTable does not refresh on fireTableChanged

Tags: java, swing, jtable

We have fairly complicated model in a JTable. In new development I noticed that GUI does not refresh when I call fireTableChanged(...) for individual cells.
So, my question is:
**What do I put into TableModelEvent - model row id or view row id?**

Looking into JTable code (I have jdk1.8.0_202):

```
public class JTable extends JComponent implements TableModelListener, Scrollable,
...
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
...
        int modelColumn = e.getColumn();
        int start = e.getFirstRow();
        int end = e.getLastRow();

        Rectangle dirtyRegion;
        if (modelColumn == TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS) {
            // 1 or more rows changed
            dirtyRegion = new Rectangle(0, start * getRowHeight(),
                                        getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), 0);
        }
        else {
            // A cell or column of cells has changed.
            // Unlike the rest of the methods in the JTable, the TableModelEvent
            // uses the coordinate system of the model instead of the view.
            // This is the only place in the JTable where this "reverse mapping"
            // is used.
            int column = convertColumnIndexToView(modelColumn);
            dirtyRegion = getCellRect(start, column, false);
        }
```

I see that in order to calculate dirty region, it converts column index, but does not do the same for row.
What does "reverse mapping" comment mean?
Looks like a bug in Swing to me.
What do you think?

**UPDATE**
My code is simple:

```
model.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(model, rowNumber, rowNumber, columnNumber));
```

GUI does NOT refresh the cell.

**UPDATE2**
The issue is in my model which is too complicated to post it here. :(

I cannot blame JTable. It is designed this way. The only possible addition to it is RowSorter, and in there it does correct conversion:

```
    private void repaintSortedRows(ModelChange change) {
...
        int modelIndex = change.startModelIndex;
        while (modelIndex <= change.endModelIndex) {
            int viewIndex = convertRowIndexToView(modelIndex++);
            if (viewIndex != -1) {
                Rectangle dirty = getCellRect(viewIndex, columnViewIndex,
                                              false);
                int x = dirty.x;
                int w = dirty.width;
                if (eventColumn == TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS) {
                    x = 0;
                    w = getWidth();
                }
                repaint(x, dirty.y, w, dirty.height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks everybody. Sorry for disturbance.

Comment: There is no need for you to play with the dirty region. A TableModelListener, simply tells you the data in the model has changed. The table will automatically repaint itself. For a working example of using a TableModelListener check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604648/jtable-tablemodelistener/5605800#5605800

Comment: You should show us **your**, not the JDK code.

Comment: My code is strait forward:

`model.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(model, rowNumber, rowNumber, columnNumber));`

GUI does not refresh the cell.

Comment: @camickr This is really simple example. JTable does not have a sorter - model row id is the same as a view row id.

Comment: Why dont you simply call model.fireTableChanged() without any arguments?

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos I need to refresh this particular cell, not the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

> My code is simple:

```
model.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(model, rowNumber, rowNumber, columnNumber));
```

That is not how you change data in a JTable. You should NOT be invoking that method directly. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke that method when data is changed.

The point of using a TableModelListener is to listen for changes in the TableModel. You only need to implement the listener if you want to do special processing AFTER the data has changed as I demonstrated in the link I provided in my comment.

If you have data in an existing cell and you want to change its value then can do something like:

```
model.setValueAt("new value", 0, 0);
```

If you want to add a new row of data you use:

```
model.addRow(...);
```

The point is all changes should be done via the TableModel.

Note the JTable also has a convenience setValueAt(...) method which will invoke the model for you.

Comment: `setValueAt()` is applicable only if you have underlying storage for your model. In case when cell value computed on a fly, GUI should be updated when `fireTableChanged()` is triggered.

Comment: @AlexP, The example I linked you to shows how to calculate a value on the fly? Did you even read the link and download the code to test it??. Your understanding of the fireTableChanged() event is wrong.  All updates need to be done to the model. The model will then generate the appropriate event so the table can repaint itself.